# R: Error in matrix(0, nrow = N, ncol = n.seq) : non-numeric matrix extent

Tags: r, matrix

```
library(RMallow)
> dput(rankings)
structure(list(MEMORY1 = c(5.5, 7, 1.5, 6, 4.5, 4.5, 5, 4, 1, 
5.5, 2.5, 4.5, 2.5, 5.5, 4, 1, 4, 5, 2.5, 5.5), MEMORY2 = c(5.5, 
3, 1.5, 6, 4.5, 4.5, 5, 4, 5, 5.5, 6.5, 4.5, 2.5, 5.5, 4, 7, 
8, 5, 6.5, 5.5), MEMORY3 = c(5.5, 3, 4.5, 2, 4.5, 4.5, 5, 4, 
5, 1.5, 6.5, 4.5, 6.5, 5.5, 4, 7, 4, 5, 6.5, 5.5), MEMORY4 = c(1.5, 
3, 4.5, 2, 1, 4.5, 5, 4, 5, 5.5, 2.5, 4.5, 2.5, 1.5, 4, 2, 4, 
5, 2.5, 1.5), MEMORY5 = c(5.5, 3, 4.5, 6, 4.5, 4.5, 5, 1, 5, 
5.5, 6.5, 4.5, 6.5, 5.5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 2.5, 1.5), MEMORY6 = c(5.5, 
7, 7.5, 6, 8, 4.5, 5, 7.5, 5, 5.5, 6.5, 4.5, 6.5, 5.5, 4, 4, 
4, 5, 2.5, 5.5), MEMORY7 = c(1.5, 3, 4.5, 2, 4.5, 4.5, 1, 4, 
5, 1.5, 2.5, 4.5, 6.5, 1.5, 4, 7, 4, 1, 6.5, 5.5), MEMORY8 = c(5.5, 
7, 7.5, 6, 4.5, 4.5, 5, 7.5, 5, 5.5, 2.5, 4.5, 2.5, 5.5, 8, 4, 
4, 5, 6.5, 5.5)), .Names = c("MEMORY1", "MEMORY2", "MEMORY3", 
"MEMORY4", "MEMORY5", "MEMORY6", "MEMORY7", "MEMORY8"), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")

abils = ncol(rankings)
R = Rgen(2, hyp = NULL, abils)
AllKendall(ranking, R)
```

When I run the above code, I get an error saying that `Error in matrix(0, nrow = N, ncol = n.seq) : non-numeric matrix extent`. I read a few other related posts and it seems like the problem is `nrow = N` is not numeric. What's causing this to happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a look at the examples in `?AllKendall` it appears that your "set of sequences" should be a matrix (see how they have a list of rankings and then they `rbind` them together?)

To this effect, try

```
AllKendall(do.call(rbind, R), do.call(rbind, rankings))
# for some reason if you put it the other way round there is an error
```

And the result is a matrix such that `output[i, j]` is the distance from sequence `i` in `R` from sequence `j` in `rankings`.